# Change shape, upscale, image array in Neural Net

Tags: python, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection, image-resizing

I have an array of image pixel values that I would like to upscale for input into my neural network. It is an array of shape (28000, 48, 48, 1). These are normalized image pixel values and would like to upscale these to a higher resolution for input into my CNN. The arrays look like this...

```
array([[[[-0.6098866 ],
         [-0.4592209 ],
         [-0.40325198],
         ...,
         [-0.7694696 ],
         [-0.90518403],
         [-0.95160526]],

        [[-0.66049284],
         [-0.68162924],
         [-0.694159  ],
```

Both my `X_train` and `y_train` image arrays have shape of (28000,48,48,1). I would like to upscale or resize these 28000 image arrays to size 75x75. Please help. Should I convert arrays back to non-normalized arrays or images and then maybe use **cv2** to upscale? How would I do this?

Comment: ever tried `scipy.misc.imresize()` or `skimage.transform.resize()` ?

Comment: Looking into this also. Just difficult for my use case of only having arrays and not the images.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

image_array = X_train[0]
img = image_array.reshape(48,48)
resized_width = 75
resized_height = 75
dimension = (resized_width, resized_height)

resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
print(resized.shape)
image_array = resized.flatten()
print(len(image_array))

Comment: The above code worked as well with cv2. This got me, after flattening, an array of length 5625 (75x75). So now I need to do this for all 28000 images to have final array of size (28000, 5625) How would I loop through and do this?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to resize images is using the Python module PIL (Python Image Library), which you can install with `pip install pillow`. Example below to demonstrate resizing a single image:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open image
panda_pil = Image.open("panda.jpg")
print(np.array(panda_pil).shape)
# (613, 696, 3)

panda_pil_resized = panda_pil.resize((75, 75))
print(np.array(panda_pil_resized).shape)
# (75, 75, 3)

plt.imshow(np.array(panda_pil_resized))
plt.show()
```

You can download the panda image as follows:

```py
import urllib.request

panda_fname = "panda.jpg"
panda_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Giant_Panda_in_Beijing_Zoo_1.JPG"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(panda_url, panda_fname)
```

To resize all 28000 images, one approach would be to do this as a preprocessing step in a for-loop, and save the images to a numpy array.

Edit: You can loop through your original 28000x2304 image array and upscale each image individually in a `for`-loop. To get the `PIL.Image` object from a `np.ndarray` object, you can use `Pil.Image.from_array`, as shown below (I have just generated a random array of Gaussian noise but it should work the same with your images):

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from time import perf_counter

old_width, old_height = 48, 48
new_width, new_height = 75, 75
num_images = 28000

old_image_array = np.random.normal(size=[num_images, old_width*old_height])
new_image_array = np.empty(shape=[num_images, new_width*new_height])

print("Starting conversion...")
t0 = perf_counter()

# Loop over each image individually
for i in range(num_images):
    # Get the ith image and reshape
    old_image = old_image_array[i].reshape(old_width, old_height)
    # Convert to PIL.Image
    old_image_pil = Image.fromarray(old_image)
    # Upscale resolution
    new_image_pil = old_image_pil.resize((new_width, new_height))
    # Convert to numpy array
    new_image = np.array(new_image_pil)
    # Reshape and store in new image array
    new_image_array[i] = new_image.reshape(new_width*new_height)

t1 = perf_counter()
print("Time taken = {:.3f} s".format(t1 - t0))
print(old_image_array.shape, new_image_array.shape)
```

Console output:

```
Starting conversion...
Time taken = 2.771 s
(28000, 2304) (28000, 5625)
```

There may well be a more efficient way of doing this, but this method is simple, and uses tools which are useful to know about if you don't know about them already (`PIL` is a good module for manipulating images, see [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/image-processing-in-python-with-pillow/) if you want to learn more about `PIL`).

Comment: Looks like that is in the right direction or a big leap towards what I am trying to achieve. My only issue is that I do not have the original images, only a csv file with 28000 rows for 48x48 images. So only have arrays not original images. You are starting off opening an image, I have no image to open.So must I convert my array to images first before resizing and using the .resize function? Im not sure how I would write this for loop out.

Comment: This is how my X_train array looks before normalization...                                               
[[ 70.  80.  82. ... 106. 109.  82.]
 [151. 150. 147. ... 193. 183. 184.]
 [231. 212. 156. ...  88. 110. 152.]]
X_train.shape -> (28000, 2304) So this is what I have to start with. How can I loop through this?

Comment: import cv2 image_array = X_train[0] img = image_array.reshape(48,48) resized_width = 75 resized_height = 75 dimension = (resized_width, resized_height) resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) print(resized.shape) image_array = resized.flatten() print(len(image_array))

Comment: The above code worked as well with cv2. This got me, after flattening, an array of length 5625 (75x75). So now I need to do this for all 28000 images to have final array of size (28000, 5625) How would I loop through and do this?

Comment: @willbecoding see my edits above. Does this answer your question?